# Looking for elegant way of generation Reactor hot stream

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have `Reactor` hot stream which polls `Redis` using reactive `Lettuce API`:

```
Flux
                    .generate(sink -> sink.next(0))
                    .flatMap(
                            r -> pollingConnection
                                    .reactive()
                                    .brpop(pollingTimeout, queue)
                    ...
                    .subscribe(subscription);
```

Is there a way to do it without `flatMap`? Any async sinks?

Comment: to do _what_? can you better try to describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Code above is the infitite hot stream which uses redis list as a source. The question was not  "how to do", but about possibility to rewrite `generate(sink -> sink.next(0)).flatMap(...)` in more elegant way. You've answered my question below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for regular non-blocking polling, I guess you would better off using `Flux.interval` rather than `Flux.generate` (which, combined to `flatMap`, will generate 256 immediate requests btw)

since the API seems to be based on a `brpop` `Publisher`, you don't have much choice but using `flatMap` if you want to trigger multiple pops.